# Camanjs vs Fabricjs - Which one to use mainly for image editing and manipulation?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs, camanjs

I am starting to build a website where users will be uploading images. I want to add feature-rich editor for images like `adding image filters, cropping, resizing, rotating, changing brightness, hue, saturation, different blur effects` and many more. 
 
Between [fabricjs](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js) and [camanjs](https://github.com/meltingice/CamanJS/) which one is better for these requirements? Fabric has more contributors on github and has good recent activity which is not the case for Caman. Would also like to have good support or community incase i run into any issues during development.

Camanjs examples: http://camanjs.com/examples/  
Fabric Examples: http://fabricjs.com/image-filters/ 
Please suggest which library to use and cons if any in using any of these two libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While i know fabricjs very good, i cannot say same for camanJS.
What i ask you is, why not use both?

CamanJS look superior for filtering abilities and layers, while fabricjs has very good interactive support, patterns and masks.

I think is very possible to build your application with fabricjs and use camanJS for filtering your fabricjs image objects.

Comment: i found a link (http://stackoverflow.com/a/32801551/2177085) which actually used both caman and fabric. Is it good from performance perspective to use 2 different libraries for this? And the main reason for me to doubt camanjs is the development for that on Github has stopped.

Comment: Performance wise the filtering is the heaviest thing you are gonna do, so which one does it better will improve overall performace. There is no performace hit just for using 2 libs instead of 1.